# Ocultar barra en SublimeText3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenos días nuevamente!

Quería consultar si alguien sabe cómo deshacerme de la barra inferior donde se muestra la ventana de ejecución del programa, me molesta demasiado que esté ahí y no sé cuál es la combinación de teclas que le corresponder para volver a ocultarla (la apreté por accidente hace 2 días y ya me tiene harto)

Comment: *View > Layout > Single*.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me estaba volviendo loco eso!